# VS 2013 express iis debugging mode don't work with windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication, iis-express

I am trying to run MVC project (imported be SVN) in VS 2013 which should work with basic windows authentication

```
<authentication mode="Windows"  >

</authentication>
```

In project properties, windows authentication is enabled and anonymous authentication is disabled.

I also checked applicationhosting.config for iis express and it is set as

```
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

and

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
                <providers>
                    <add value="Negotiate" />
                    <add value="NTLM" />
                </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>
```

So everything should work fine, but when I start debug mode the browser runs and ask for credentials to the computer, when provided it return 401.0 Unauthorized.

Does anybody have some experience with this behaviour? Other apllication with froms auth run with no problem on this express iis.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you authorising via isinRole?

Comment: If it is full IIS, i will recommend you use Failed Request Tracing to learn how returns 401.0 (does not sound like an IIS behavior). You should be able to do so for IIS Express, but changing the settings might take you some time to learn how to use appcmd of IIS Express or edit the config file manually.